# Get the category from an ID of a product?

Tags: plugins, categories

I have the `ID` from a product (`1345`) how can i get the category name of that specific product?

I try

```
$post_categories = wp_get_post_categories( $post->ID );
print_r( $post_categories );
```

but it outputs:

```
Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( )
```

What those it means ?

Thanks

Comment: What does the ID represent? What is a 'product'? Is this a custom post type? A meta field? What?

Comment: Hi, It's a woocommerce product and it's a post type.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since the question is tagged woocommerce, i'm assuming that it's a product CPT created by woocommerce wordpress plugin. This answer doesn't apply if that's not the case.

The products categories is not normal categories, they are a custom taxonomy created specifically for products which is just labeled as "Categories".

You should go through the woocommerce documentation to find some function that would do this for you, if you don't find anything you can try an alternative solution. For that, first you should know the name of the taxonomy. You can copy it from inside the url in your browser when you visit categories edit screen in the backend. Then you can use [`wp_get_post_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/) to get the terms.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. And yes is a woocommerce product in wordpress. Ok, i'm going to try it, what are the $args for  wp_get_post_terms ? i see the "taxonomy" and "args" are optional, so i'm going to try only with the ID.

Comment: It won't work only with ID. The default taxonomy is `post_tag`. You need to pass the name of the taxonomy there. It will work without `$args` but you can use it if you want. It's meant to override the defaults as explained on [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms)

Comment: I tested but it doesn't output the categiry that the product is in. I used this, <?php $term_list = wp_get_post_terms(1345, 'product_tag', array("fields" => "all"));
print_r($term_list);
?>

Comment: it outputs this :Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 104 [name] => new [slug] => new [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 104 [taxonomy] => product_tag [description] => Hola qué tal esto es una descripción? [parent] => 0 [count] => 8 ) ) Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 104 [name] => new [slug] => new [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 104 [taxonomy] => product_tag [description] => Hola qué tal esto es una descripción? [parent] => 0 [count] => 8 ) )

Comment: And there's not category in the array ? Did i do something wrong?

Comment: You used `product_tag`. Is it possible that the category name was `product_category`? The code seems fine & as from the output you're getting a term named `new` with an id of 104. Is `new` the name of one of the tags?

Answer (score 20):

**Option #1**

Get all product_cat's using this function

```
global $product;

$terms = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat' );
```

[Offical docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/)

---

**Option #2**
If you only need their ids, you can get all product_category_ids associated with a specific **product**, using this function:

```
global $product;

$product_cats_ids = wc_get_product_term_ids( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat' );
```

[Official docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_product_term_ids.html)

---

**Extra**

If you would like to print out - for instance - the categories names, you need the category term-object. This can be retrieved using `get_term_by()`.

An example:

```
foreach( $product_cats_ids as $cat_id ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $cat_id, 'product_cat' );

    echo $term->name;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I answered my own question, this work for me :

```
<?php 
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($id_product,'product_cat',array('fields'=>'ids'));
$cat_id = (int)$term_list[0];
echo get_term_link ($cat_id, 'product_cat');

?>
```

Thanks Mridul Aggarwal for your help

Comment: You could at least upvote Mridul's answer, if you don't think it's complete enough to be accepted as correct. Clearly it got you on the right track.

Comment: you can use `$product->get_id()` to know "$id_product"

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
   $terms = get_the_terms($product->ID, 'product_cat');
       foreach ($terms as $term) {

         $product_cat = $term->name;
            echo $product_cat;
              break;
          }
   ?>
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?